# How to have different Project Dependencies for each Project Configuration on VS2017?

Tags: c#, configuration, linker, dependencies, visual-studio-2017

I've the same question of [How to have different Project Dependencies for each Project Configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519060/how-to-have-different-project-dependencies-for-each-project-configuration), but the provided solution is very outdated and I'm not able to reproduce it on VS2017.

I'm receiving this error, and I don't know how to exclude the project from the linking.

> Error CS0006  Metadata file 'path\to\my\excluded\library.dll' could not be found

Comment: Assuming you are using the new csproj format, Could you possibly provide the csproj file that has this problem?

Comment: Is a WPF project with .net framework 4.6.2, it has the old format

Comment: Does your solution use a combination of old libraries and new? (ie new csproj formats with old formats)

Comment: No, only old projects with .net framework 4.6.2. I've unchecked the build checkbox on the configuration manager for the unwanted project, and removed with pre-compilation conditions any reference on code.

Answer (score 0):

I've realized that the best way to perform this is to create a new root project with different dependencies, and choose by configuration which to compile.